# Initialize variables in one time with map containing nested IndexedSeq

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sequence

I search of method to resolve this initialization problem of tuple () with result of a map, like this :

```
//My current state of cities
val listOfCity = IndexedSeq(new City1(), new City2())

// Function which compute my new state
val (newCity,exchange) = listOfCity.map{ city =>  computeNewCity(city,listOfCity)}
```

The variable `newCity` contain the result ._1 of my tuple returned by `computeNewCity()` and the variable `exchange` contain the result ._2 of the same tuple.

The function `computeNewCity()` return a new version of my object city and an history of exchange, results of my exchange with other cities in `listOfCity`, it's a tuple of type `(City, Exchange)`

How can i make this with help of functionnal programming ?

Thanks !
Sr

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you want to do. Could you include the desired result?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it's more clear with this update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `listOfCity.map{ city =>  computeNewCity(city,listOfCity)}` returns an `IndexedSeq[(City, Exchange)]` (one tuple for each city in `listOfCity`), and obviously you can't just assign it to a `(City, Exchange)` tuple. You could take first element or last:

```
val (firstCity,exchange) = listOfCity.map{ city =>  computeNewCity(city,listOfCity)}.first

val (lastCity,exchange) = listOfCity.map{ city =>  computeNewCity(city,listOfCity)}.last
```

or get a tuple of two sequences (cities and their corresponding exchanges)

```
val (cities,exchanges) = listOfCity.map{ city =>  computeNewCity(city,listOfCity)}.unzip
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you’re trying to do?

```
scala> val Seq(a, b) =  IndexedSeq(IndexedSeq(3.0,2.0), IndexedSeq(1.0))
a: IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(3.0, 2.0)
b: IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(1.0)
```

Comment: @reyman64 But it is still not clear what you're trying to do. Please tell us what you'd expect.